# How can I set a name for a table's columns autosave feature in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, nstableview

I'm attempting to save a NSTableView's columns by setting the autosave feature in the xib thus:[image: see the picture]
But when I run, the app hangs with this in the console: *Column identifiers used with NSTableView autosave feature must be a valid NSString*.
How on earth can I do that in the xib?
PS I did this several times last week with no problems. (Xcode 9.2)

Comment: How did you do it last week?

Comment: I've just changed the project's target's Swift Language version from 3 to 4. Don't know why it wasn't already set to the latest version for a new project. Seems to have fixed it, but this hardly constitutes an answer so I'll leave it as a comment. Should I withdraw the question?

Comment: Cancel the last comment. It hasn't fixed it, or if it did, it was only temporary.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the error message carefully enough. It was the table's *column* identifiers that needed setting. I'd left them on `automatic` as I didn't need to refer to them anywhere else. Gave them meaningful names. Job done.